# View the log in WildFly Cartridges in OpenShift

Tags: openshift, wildfly

I'm starting to use OpenShift and I tried to deploy a application that are already use WildFly, I installed de WildFly Cartridges and configure de standalone.xml from the Source Code but when I restarted de application WildFly didn't start so I believe that is because a fail in the standalone.xml but I don't know how I can see the logs to really understand why fail to start the server.

Additionally I add a keystore in .openshift\config and configured it in the standalone.xml like this:

```
    <server-identities>
        <ssl>
             <keystore path="localhost.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="XXXX" alias="XXXX" key-password="XXXX"/>
         </ssl>
    </server-identities>
```

I don’t know if the keystore is in the right place or I need to copy it in other place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the rhc tail command, or ssh int your gear and look in your ~/app-root/logs directory.

Answer (score 0):

The command rhc tail -a appname will tail all application log files in the OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR directory for the primary web gear of the application.

```
 rhc tail -a appname
```

To stop tailing the logs, press Ctrl + c.

Tailing Specific Files

The -f option can be appended to the tail command to specify a particular file to tail. The wild card (*) character can be used to specify multiple files. The path given should be relative to the OpenShift application user’s home directory on the gear.

The following example tails all files in the OpenShift log directory with a name starting with php.log, which includes files with a time stamp appended to their name.

```
rhc tail -f app-root/logs/php.log* -a myapp
```

for Custom Tail and other Options

see https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-log-files.html